# Issue in enabling SSO2 for WSO2 server

Tags: authentication, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm configuring SSO for EMM from :
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/General+Server+Configurations

And enabling SSO2 for WSO2 server from : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+SSO+for+WSO2+Servers#EnablingSSOforWSO2Servers-ConfiguringWSO2GovernanceRegistry

I've downloaded latest versions of:
WSO2 Application Server - 5.3.0
WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus - 4.9.0
WSO2 Governance Registry - 5.1.0
WSO2 Identity Server - 5.1.0

I followed steps but I think documentation is not updated and when I try access the Application Server: https://localhost:9444/carbon/ on browser I'm redirected to the Identity Server for authentication, but once I give credentials it gives following error

**Command Prompt**
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SP
InitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor} -  ALERT: Invalid Assertion Consumer URL value 'https://172.20.1.171:9444/acs' in the AuthnRequest message from  the issuer 'carbonServer'. Possibly an attempt for a spoofing attack.

**Browser**

SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On

Error when processing the authentication request!
Please try login again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the ACS url you have provided. You can solve this by updating the ACS URL from https://localhost:9444/carbon/ to https://172.20.1.171:9444/acs in the Service Provider.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ACS url in your authenticatoin request is 'https://172.20.1.171:9444/acs'. But you have configured something else for following in the SAML configuration(with issuer "carbonServer").

[image]

Make sure both values are same.